# Create an object based on file path string

Tags: javascript

Given the path "documents/settings/user"

How can this be made into a nested object

Result

```
{
   documents : {
         settings : {
               user : {}
          } 
    }
}
```

I can't think of how to reference each previous path

```
var dir = {};

var paths = "documents/settings/user".split('/')
for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
  var path = paths[i];
  if(i === 0)
        dir[path] = {};
  //else
    //dir[path[i-?]] = {};
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually done quite easily with `.reduce()`.

```js
var dir = {}

var paths = "documents/settings/user".split('/')

paths.reduce(function(dir, path) {
  return dir[path] = {}
}, dir)

console.log(dir)
```

Because the first parameter is always the last value returned *(or the first value provided)*, all we need to do is return the object being assigned to the current path. And because an assignment results in the value being assigned, we can use that as the expression of the `return` statement itself.

---

If needed, you can guard against empty path names due to adjacent separators.

```js
var dir = {}

var paths = "documents///settings/user".split('/')

paths.reduce(function(dir, path) {
  return path ? (dir[path] = {}) : dir
}, dir)

console.log(dir)
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. Just check [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Browser_compatibility) before using. You can even add [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce#Polyfill) for incompatible browsers

Comment: @Rajesh: Good point. Needs a patch for very old JS implementations.

Comment: Another great answer. Its ok I am on Node.js

Answer (score 3):

Yet another elegant solution to build an object with value:

```
const buildObjWithValue = (path, value = '') => {
    const paths = path.split('.');
    return paths.reduceRight((acc, item, index) => ({
        [item]: index === paths.length - 1
            ? value
            : acc
    }), {});
}
```

For example `buildObjWithValue('very.deep.lake', 'Baikal')` gives us

```
{
  very: {
    deep: {
      lake: 'Bailkal'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Object`s are passed by reference. You can use this feature and do something like this.

#### Array.forEach

```js
var paths = "documents/settings/user".split('/')
var r = {};
var _tmp = r;
paths.forEach(function(el){
  _tmp[el] = {};
  _tmp = _tmp[el];
});

console.log(r)
```

#### For

```js
var paths = "documents/settings/user".split('/')
var r = {};
var _tmp = r;
for(var i=0; i<paths.length; i++){
  _tmp = (_tmp[paths[i]] = {});
};

console.log(r)
```

Comment: Wow... really great. Thanks.